# How to call oracle Store procedure in Apache NiFi

Tags: stored-procedures, apache-nifi, nifi-processor

I need to use ORACLE stored procedure with input param and this input PARAM is coming from flow file and get output from that stored procedure. is any processor is available with run stored procedure and return the out put in avro schema or any other format? Please help me.

Comment: Have a look at this - https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Execute-Stored-Procedure-of-MSSQL-in-Nifi/td-p/213365

Comment: this solution is not working for me

Comment: what do you mean by `not working` - are you getting any exceptions or failures at any other place?

Comment: its saying invalid SQL statement

Comment: Are you using any statement terminator like `;`? Is it possible to provide SQL statement?

Comment: found the solution. thanks

Comment: Please add your solution as the answer, it might be helpful for someone, thanks!

Comment: http://funnifi.blogspot.com/2016/04/sql-in-nifi-with-executescript.html --> solution is given in this link. Please refer